# How to extract sub-list information of identical elements in two different nested lists and storing them?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I was looking for your help for the following and I am new to Python. Thank you in advance.

I have 2 example nested lists:

```
list1 = [['*1', '*2'], ['*3', '*4'], ['*5', '*6', '+1', '+4'], ['+2', '+5', '+3']]

list2 = [['*2', '*6', '*1', '+4', '*4'], ['*3', '*5', '+3', '+5'], ['+1'], ['+2']]
```

Both nested lists have identical string elements but located in different sublists.

For each element in the two nested lists, I need to:

1. Find which sublist number it is occurring in list1. For example, `'*1'` in `list1` is in sublist 1, `'*6'` in `list1` is in sublist 3, and so on for all elements. So I need to create a dictionary with each of these string elements as keys and the sublist number in `list1` as values.

```
Desired Output:
list1_location = {'*1': '1', '*2': '1', '*3': '2', '*4': '2', '*5': '3', '*6': '3', '+1': '3', '+4': '3', '+2': '4', '+5': '4', '+3': '4'}
```

2. Find which sublist number it is occurring in list2. For example, `'*5'` in `list2` is in sublist 2, `'+2'` in `list2` is in sublist 4, and so on for all elements. So I need to create a dictionary with each of these string elements as keys and the sublist number in `list2` as values.

```
Desired Output:
list2_location = {'*2': '1', '*6': '1', '*1': '1', '+4': '1', '*4': '1', '*3': '2', '*5': '2', '+3': '2', '+5': '2', '+1': '3', '+2': '4'}
```

3. To find the (difference + 1) for each of these elements based on its sublist location in list1 and list2. For example, `'*1'` in `list1` is at sublist 1 and `'*1'` in `list2` is at sublist 1. So, (list1 - list2 + 1)= (1-1+1)= 1. Similarly, `'*6'` in `list1` is at sublist 3 and `'*6'` in `list2` is at sublist 1. So, (list1 - list2 + 1)= (3-1+1)= 3. So I need to create a dictionary with each of these string elements as keys and the difference `(list1 - list2 + 1)` as values.

```
Desired Output:
diff_dict = {'*1': '1', '*2': '1', '*3': '1', '+1': '1', '+2': '1', '*4': '2', '*5': '2', '*6': '3', '+3': '3', '+4': '3', '+5': '3'}
```

I was trying the following:

```
list1 = [['*1', '*2'], ['*3', '*4'], ['*5', '*6', '+1', '+4'], ['+2', '+5', '+3']]
list2 = [['*2', '*6', '*1', '+4', '*4'], ['*3', '*5', '+3', '+5'], ['+1'], ['+2']]
new_list = []
for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if i[0] == j[0]:
                 new_list.append(j)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def index_tracker(list_):
    return {item : i + 1 for i, sub_list in enumerate(list_) for item in sub_list}

list1_location = index_tracker(list1)
list2_location = index_tracker(list2)

diff_dict = {k: str(v - list2_location[k] + 1) for k, v in list1_location.items()}

>>> print(diff_dict)
>>> {'*1': '1', '*2': '1', '*3': '1', '*4': '2', '*5': '2', '*6': '3', '+1': '1', '+4': '3', '+2': '1', '+5': '3', '+3': '3'}
```